# Is It Dirty Read?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I have 1 transaction to do some business flow with 2 logics.

**Logic A** is responsible of updating some columns in table.

**Logic B** is responsible of getting some data but croscutting with Logic A.

Let's say I have a table like the one below.

```
+----+------------------+------------+
| ID |      WEBSITE     | IS_VISITED |
+----+------------------+------------+
|  1 |  www.google.com  |      0     |
+----+------------------+------------+
|  2 |  www.youtube.com |      0     |
+----+------------------+------------+
|  3 | www.facebook.com |      0     |
+----+------------------+------------+
```

Than Logic A comes and it run this query without committed.

```
UPDATE my_table SET IS_VISITED = 1 WHERE ID in (1,2)
```

Than in same transaction Logic B comes, and it run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE IS_VISITED = 0
```

Query result is:

```
+----+------------------+------------+
| ID |      WEBSITE     | IS_VISITED |
+----+------------------+------------+
|  3 | www.facebook.com |      0     |
+----+------------------+------------+
```

Is it dirty read? Can you help me to understand what's going on?